# Selective Column Rendering

Tags: visualforce

Is there a way to view certain columns based on a condition. For example, I want columns to be rendered based on the data type of an object.

What I mean is like this:

```
<apex:column rendered="test.data_type == Select List">
</apex:column>
```

Also, I want multiple columns to be generated depending on how many specific data types are in that object. If it has two items with string data type, it should render two columns in the output with string input fields. P.S. I have no experience with javascript, if that is part of your answer. Thank you.

To elaborate, what I want to do is that the user would be able to choose an item from a drop down menu and then they can press an add button. This will cause a a table with 2 columns and one or more rows to generated. Each row would have a name field and an input or output. The items are created in a different setup page and the page I am talking about will generate line items based on my item setup. So for different items there could be a different amount of rows and they should also be able to add multiple items so they are stackable.

Comment: data_type - it is picklist on Object? Or you mean diffrent types of objects?

Comment: its suppose to be a field for my object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below is some Visualforce that makes use of `rendered` on `apex:column` to change the markup for various named columns. So the answer to your question is **yes**.

```
<apex:pageBlockTable var="item" value="{!tasks}">
    <apex:column headerValue="Action" styleClass="actionColumn">
        <apex:outputLink value="/{!item.Id}/e" title="Edit Task" styleClass="actionLink">Edit</apex:outputLink>
    </apex:column>
    <apex:repeat var="f" value="{!fields}">
        <apex:column rendered="{! f != 'OwnerId' && f != 'Description' && f != 'Subject'}" value="{!item.task[f]}"/>
        <apex:column rendered="{! f == 'Subject'}" style="white-space: nowrap">
            <apex:facet name="header">Subject</apex:facet>
            <apex:outputLink value="/{!item.task.Id}">{!item.title}</apex:outputLink>
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column rendered="{! f == 'Description'}">
            <apex:facet name="header">Comments</apex:facet>
            <apex:outputText value="{!item.task[f]}"/>
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column rendered="{! f == 'OwnerId'}" headerValue="Assigned To" value="{!item.task.OwnerId}"/>
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

A bit more explanation... Two lists (provided by the controller) are involved. The `tasks` list is a list of SObjects where each SObject is to be displayed as a row of the table. The `fields` list is a list of the SObject field names to display where each field is displayed as a column of the table. So it is the job of the controller using describe information or other configuration to build the lists and it is the job of the page to render each column using the appropriate markup.

If you want your logic to be driven by the type of each SObject field then that can be obtained using describe calls (`DescribeFieldResult.getType()`) and also made available to the page.

I have not done this using input fields so there may be some gotchas there.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what this line does exactly? Such as the syntax. rendered="{! f != 'OwnerId' && f != 'Description' && f != 'Subject'}". I am a beginner so I am not sure exactly what is going on. Also please look at my edited question if it helps, I added some more details.

Comment: @ths the best way to learn about Visualforce syntax is to work through the various tutorials. The addition to your question suggests you are working on something non-trivial and that will be extra hard if you have no experience of the tools you are aiming to use.

Comment: thank you for your help. I will be going through the tutorials and now I believe I understand everything better as well.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure if I understood your question, but you can use the standard `apex:inputField` and `apex:outputField` components to dynamically display correct input fields based on the field type.

> An HTML input element for a value that corresponds to a field on a
>   Salesforce object. **The  component respects the
>   attributes of the associated field, including whether the field is
>   required or unique**, and the user interface widget to display to get
>   input from the user. For example, **if the specified 
>   component is a date field, a calendar input widget is displayed**. When
>   used in an ,  tags always
>   display with their corresponding output label.

[inputfield documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_inputField.htm) - 
[outputfield documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_outputField.htm)