# Display list of list on visual force page. Search results of inputtext from all objects using sosl

Tags: apex, visualforce, sosl, dynamic

I am trying to search for a text from all the objects. The method in the controller returns the results as List of List. I am trying to display the results in the visualforce page but no results get displayed on the page. On debug log I can see the answer. I am not sure why the results are not getting displayed. Also I want the null results not to be displayed. Can any one help o nit.

VF Page:

```
<apex:page controller="objectList">     
<apex:form >
   Input Text1 <apex:inputText value="{!inputText1}"/>
   <apex:commandButton value="search" action="{!getQueryString}"/>
  <apex:repeat value="{!myNotes}" var="note">
  <apex:repeat value="{!note}" var="item">
    <apex:outputText value="{!item}" /><br/>
  </apex:repeat>
</apex:repeat>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public class objectList{
   public String myNotes { get; set; }
   public String getQueryString { get; set; }
   public String inputText1{get;set;} 
   List<Schema.SObjectType> gd{get;set;}

   public pageReference getQueryString()
   {
     getQueryString2(); 
     return null; 
   }    

   public List<List<SObject>> getQueryString2()
   {
    System.debug('you reached here');
    List<List<SObject>> searchList;
    List<String> strQuery1 = new List<String>();
    String strQuery = '';
    String query = '';

    gd = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().Values();
    for(Schema.SObjectType f : gd)
    {
          if(f.getdescribe().issearchable())
            strQuery1.add(f.getDescribe().getName());
        //System.debug(f.getDescribe().getName());
    }

    for(String str: strQuery1)
    {
      strQuery+= str+',';
      System.debug(strQuery);
    }

    String strQuery2 = strQuery.substringBeforeLast(','); 
    query = 'FIND \'' + inputText1+ '\' IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING ' + strQuery2;

    System.debug(query);
    searchList = search.query(query);

    System.debug(searchList);
    return searchList;
   }          
}
```

Comment: We can't see in your code a place where you bind the query results with the UI. Please edit the question and add related codes

Comment: I updated the code controller code to  :public List<List<SObject>> myNotes { get; set; }   so now it should get binded to UI

Comment: I got it binded to the UI by the change but I only get the ID of the output and not the list of all the columns in the list.

Comment: I was able to bind the answer to the UI but am only able to see the ID as the result output. If I want to list all the columns in the list, could you please help on it. <output text value -"{!item['name']}" will not work for all dynamic columns from the results. Basically when I search a text from all the SObjects from Salesforce, it returns me a list of SObjects along with the fields where the text was found. I want to display those object names and columns in the results. Then I want to embed Salesforce stylesheet to them and hide global search and replace my search with it.

Comment: do I need to create another method which iterates through the list to find out all the fields in the object and then bind it to the pageblock repeat to display the results

Answer (score 3):

You are not making the search results visible via a property and also need to make the property have an appropriate type:

```
public class objectList{
    public List<List<SObject>> myNotes { get; set; }
    ...
    public pageReference getQueryString() {
        myNotes = getQueryString2(); 
        return null; 
    }
    ...
}
```

Assuming you would like to see one or more fields of the object output you can reference the fields by their API names like this:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!myNotes}" var="note">
    <apex:repeat value="{!note}" var="item">
        <apex:outputText value="{!item['name']}" /><br/>
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:repeat>
```

You should also guard against [SOSL injection attacks](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dynamic_sosl.htm):

```
query = 'FIND \'' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(inputText1) + ...;
```

I'm not sure what the "null results" you mention are.

Comment: when you see the output of the sosl query it also posts the null lists including the result lists which has the search text as an value

Comment: I was able to bind the answer to the UI but am only able to see the ID as the result output. If I want to list all the columns in the list, could you please help on it. <output text value -"{!item['name']}" will not work for all dynamic columns from the results. Basically when I search a text from all the SObjects from Salesforce, it returns me a list of SObjects along with the fields where the text was found. I want to display those object names and columns in the results. Then I want to embed Salesforce stylesheet to them and hide global search and replace my search with it.

Comment: do I need to create another method which iterates through the list to find out all the fields in the object and then bind it to the pageblock repeat to display the results.

Comment: @ravi Yes, expose the list of field names and add another loop inside the existing loops. You can use apex:pageBlockTable and apex:column in that way too.

Comment: @ravo Example (with more complexity than you need_ here http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/28199/selective-column-rendering/28214#28214.